# Error during the execution of command "sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, linux

I am getting the following error after execution of the command "sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer"

Note: I have an application which have the dependency in Java 6.I feel java 6 is obsolete. But still is there any other way to install this.

### Error:

```
Setting up oracle-java6-installer (6u45-0~webupd8~8) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 6...
--2018-03-21 13:37:46--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.56.176.183
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.56.176.183|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin [following]
--2018-03-21 13:37:47--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 184.50.117.49, 2600:1417:75:199::2d3e, 2600:1417:75:19c::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|184.50.117.49|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1521619788_32d3144ce18a102db8f7ec93e2650e1c [following]
--2018-03-21 13:37:48--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1521619788_32d3144ce18a102db8f7ec93e2650e1c
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.56.176.183|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-03-21 13:37:50 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 6 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java6-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java6-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you done a `sudo apt-get update` beforehand? Looks like they moved the package to another address (or changed the package name due to a version bump).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to download the jre 6 manually from the oracle website
[JRE SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html)

Edit: After accepting the license, you will be asked to login. You can register a free account and continue to download

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is no longer possible to download java 6, Oracle does not provided it to public anymore. The only way to download such version is to have a support contract with Oracle. Have a look at this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847852/why-cant-i-install-oracle-java-6)

Comment: oracle does provide an option to download it. see my answer

Comment: The link post I gave has a link that redirects to the same download page you gave in your answer. The main issue is that if you try to download java it requires you to log in, but to have such login requirements you need to contact Oracle

Comment: you can register a free account and download it. I just tried it and it works

Comment: Ok perfect, I didn't try creating an account to check if it was possible to download.